TypeError: Object of type FieldInfo is not JSON serializable
I am building a simple RAG usin ChatNvidia as my llm but I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Object of type FieldInfo is not JSON serializable 
each time I try running this code:
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnablePassthrough


def format_docs(docs):
    return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)


rag_chain = (
    {"context": retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
    | prompt
    | llm
    | StrOutputParser()
)

for chunk in rag_chain.stream("What is Task Decomposition?"):
    print(chunk, end="", flush=True)

can someone help me.
I have tried debugging to see where the error is coming from but I can't seem to figure it out. The code is supposed to prompt my llm to give me response but it is giving me issues.

Nothing in this code does json serialization, so the error must be happening in other code that you haven't shown.  Please post the full error traceback message, so we don't have to guess where the error happens.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
